# audio should stop while app is in background (flutter webview)

Tags: javascript, flutter

I'm facing an issue in flutter web view, audio is playing in the background I want to stop it when the home button is pressed. webpage is made with HTML,CSS and js.
https://readnplay.co/wp-content/uploads/books/with%20text%20box/How%20to%20be%20an%20otter/

this is a book that is present on the app

```
return Scaffold(
  floatingActionButton: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // BookButton._interstitialAd?.dispose();
        if (randomNumber >= 9) {
          SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
              [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const NewsLetterPage(),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
              [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniStartTop,
  body: Stack(
    children: [
      WebView(
        initialUrl: widget.url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onPageFinished: (finish) {
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        },
      ),
      _isLoading
          ? Center(
              child: Lottie.asset("images/30206-loading.json"),
            )
          : Stack(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}
audio code:

var aid = document.getElementById('audio01');

```
  $('.music').bind('touchstart click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (aid.paused) {
      aid.play();
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/music.png)");
    } else {
      aid.pause();
      $(this).css("background-image", "url(images/music_s.png)");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Are you looking to do this in the webpage? If so, could you share the audio playing code also

Comment: im trying to do it in flutter if there is no other way i have to do it js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few options:

1. If you have control over the webpage, you can use JavaScript to pause the audio when the tab is no longer active
2. If you need to do this programmatically in Flutter, you should be able to use `evaluateJavascript` to execute the pause command
3. If this is only needed when the view is navigated away from and/ or you don't have control over the webpage, then you can destroy the webview onDestroy

---

#### Option #1 - Pause audio when page no longer active (JavaScript)

You can detect when a webpage changes state to background, using the [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) event.

For example:

```js
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', event => {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    // Resume music
    backgroundMusic.play();
  } else {
    // Pause music
    backgroundMusic.pause();
  }
});
```

---

#### Option #2 - Execute pause command within webview

Or, in Flutter you should be able to execute JavaScript on your web view to pause the music

```dart
_webviewController.evaluateJavascript("window.backgroundMusic.pause()");
```

---

#### Option #3 - Destroy webview when no longer needed

If you intend to stop the music when the view is navigated away from, then you could kill the webview all together. For example:

```dart
public void destroyWebView() {
    myWebView.removeAllViews();
    myWebView.clearHistory();
    myWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    myWebView.onPause();
    myWebView.removeAllViews();
    myWebView.destroyDrawingCache();
    myWebView.destroy();
    myWebView = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Workaround for audio playing in background webview_flutter 4.4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO4IG.png)

One other work around is that you pause the media on navigation to the new route using javascript . implementation done in webview_flutter 4.4.2, here is my example :

```
..addJavaScriptChannel(
‘PageOpen',
onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage message) async {
// Pause all videos and audios before starting the navigation
_controller?.runJavaScript(
'document.querySelectorAll("video, audio").forEach(media => media.pause());'
);

final int pageId = int.parse(message.message);
Navigator.of(context)
    .push(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => pageview(pageId: pageId),
    ))
    .then((_) {
      // executed after returning back to this page
      // You can add use case here if you need to perform any action when returning back
    });
},
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).